# AFNetworking in ARC gives compiler warnings after adding -fno-obc-arc

Tags: automatic-ref-counting, afnetworking

I have an ARC project and I'm trying to add AFNetworking to it. In the Build Phases for the target, I marked all the AFNetworking files with the "-fno-objc-arc" flag.  But I'm still getting quite a few compiler warnings, such as "Method possibly missing a [super dealloc] call", and "No 'assign', 'copy' or 'retain' attribute specified, assign assumed", which is sometimes followed by "Default property attribute 'assign' not appropriate for non-gc object".

All the examples about AFNetworking that I've seen, say that if I set the compiler flag, the files should compile without errors or warnings.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems AFNetworking now compiles with ARC, so no `-fno-objc-arc` flag is required. In non-ARC-projects you need to mark AFNetworking files with `-fobjc-arc`. 
AFNetworking also dropped iOS 4 support in a recent commit.

Comment: cant convert my whole project using Edit->Reflector->converttoARC because it gives me error in `AFNetworking` file `AFJSONRequestOperation.h` and some other i downloaded `AFNetworking` from here https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

Comment: If oyu take out the comment that is causing the issue you can convert it. Then put the comment back in and everything should be fine :)